# error in xcode after pod install firebase

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am getting this error in the screenshot after trying to pod install firebase

My xcode version is 8.2

[image]

this is the content of my podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Forsa' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Forsa
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'


end
```

Comment: Did you open the workspace file or the project file with Xcode?

Comment: xcode project file

Comment: You need to open the cocoapods created `PROJECTNAME.xcworkspace` file instead.

Comment: @Alper ok thanks a lot

Comment: @Alper Thanks for helping. Can you write it up as an answer, so it can be upvoted/accepted?

Comment: See the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file that cocoapods created: `PROJECTNAME.xcworkspace` (instead of the `PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj` file) to get access to the installed frameworks.

Or like they say in their documentation:

> Make sure to always open the Xcode workspace instead of the project
>   file when building your project:
>
> `$ open App.xcworkspace`